# PHP SameSite session problem, session doesn't work

Tags: php, session, cookies, samesite

I hope anybody can give me some ideas to my problem. I am trying to apply SameSite cookie to make session work but it seems it doesn't work. The visited site html:

```
<iframe src="https://www.example.com/test/iframe.php"></iframe>
```

Iframe source site:

```
    <?php
    header('Set-Cookie: cross-site-cookie=PHPSESSID; SameSite=None; Secure');
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['test'])){
        echo 1;
        $_SESSION['test'] = 'ee2';
    }else{
        echo $_SESSION['test'];
    }
```

If I visit the website, I still receive `A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at https://www.example.com/ was set without the SameSite attribute. It has been blocked, as Chrome now only delivers cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with SameSite=None and Secure.` message in browser console and session is not saved.

Strange thing is that the cookie has been actually set:
[image]

Am I missing something? Why do I get this message in console if cross-site-cookie is set and what could be reasons for session to not work? I am using php 7.1.33. If I open iframe directly, it works and it also works properly if I open the site with browser where I haven't enabled the SameSite by default cookies flag for testing.

Comment: `$_SESSION['test']` what is the value? ur setting a cookie not the session.

Comment: Yes but session seems to not work because of PHPSESSID cookie I guess. The value will be always empty, even if I refresh the page, value doesn't get stored into $_SESSION['test']. But if I open iframe directly it will store value 'ee2'.

Comment: first, call, set the `session` and `cookie` before you can check i the `session` is set or not

Answer (score 14):

I resolved it by editing .htaccess

```
<ifmodule mod_headers.c>
Header always edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;SameSite=None;Secure
</ifmodule>
```

Comment: Note that this breaks Apple Safari 12.x and older have a bug which incorrectly interprets `SameSite=None` as `SameSite=Strict`. Those browsers require that `Set-Cookie` line doesn't say anything about `SameSite` to get the behavior of `SameSite=None`.

Answer (score 13):

Set session & cookies param php: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php
Browser:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite

```
<?php
session_set_cookie_params(["SameSite" => "Strict"]); //none, lax, strict
session_set_cookie_params(["Secure" => "true"]); //false, true
session_set_cookie_params(["HttpOnly" => "true"]); //false, true
session_start(); //everything before this
```

OR php.ini:

```
[Session]
session.cookie_samesite = "Strict"
session.cookie_secure = 1
session.cookie_httponly = 1
```

Comment: This is the answer, but keep in mind that setting `Secure` or `HttpOnly` to *anything*, including `false`, will enable it in the cookie. To turn off either of those properties, don't set them to anything, that is, don't call `session_set_cookie_params` on them.

Answer (score 5):

I temporary resolved my problem using htaccess:

```
Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;SameSite=None;Secure
```

Answer (score 4):

I resolved it by:

```
<?php

session_start();
header('Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID= ' . session_id() . '; SameSite=None; Secure');
```

Comment: Please restore your question, so that this thread can still be useful for future readers. They might encounter the same issue as you did.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a class for this.

https://github.com/ovunctukenmez/SameSiteSessionStarter

It also checks if the browser supports samesite parameter properly.

Instead of session_start();
Use like the this:

```
<?php
require_once 'SameSiteSessionStarter.php';

//start samesite none php session
SameSiteSessionStarter::session_start();
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that [this worked for me](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php#125072) - setting SameSite as "None" - and some more info on what that means [here](https://php.watch/articles/PHP-Samesite-cookies).

Apparently, browsers no longer allow you to set whatever you want in an iframe, I was trying to handle a session in an iframe, loaded on a different domain and while doing that, I noticed that a different session was being created for the OTHER domain instead of what I was loading in the iframe. This seems to have fixed it. I am still testing but it's the first thing that worked since I started looking for a fix this morning.